# Use PrimeFaces Lazyloading In Datatable

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datatable, lazy-loading

I take Data from Database with Hibernate .and I show data in datatable in my program
now I have to show data with lazy loading Primefaces Datatable

I don't know how should I change my Code. I search internet, I don't find anyway.
(I want List testList with lazy loading in Datatable showing)

XHTML file:

```
<p:dataTable var="test" value="#{testMB.testList}" id="testTable"width="100%" liveResize="true">
```

ManagedBean file

```
private List<TestDTO> testList = new ArrayList<TestDTO>();
public List<TestDTO> getTestList() {
    return logList;
}
public void setTestList(final List<TestDTO> pTestList) {
    testist = pTestList;
}
```

TestDTO class

```
public class TestDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXL;

    private String XXXXXXXX;
    private Date XXXXXXXX;
    private String XXXXXXXX;
    private Long XXXXXXXX;
    private Long XXXXXXXX;
    private Long XXXXXXXX;
    private String XXXXXXXX;
    private String XXXXXXXX;
    ........
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement LazyDataModel class for lazy loading instead of using normal ArrayList and you should set lazy to true at your datatable.

```
<p:dataTable var="test" value="#{testMB.testList}" id="testTable"width="100%" liveResize="true" lazy="true">
```

You might consider turn on paginator as well as it serves the purpose of lazy loading.

More Info: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Sample of a LazyDataModel class.

```
class LazyTestDataModel extends LazyDataModel<TestDTO> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<TestDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
            Map<String, Object> filters) {
        try {

            Map<String, Object> params = PrimefacesBeanUtils.populatePaginationMap(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);

            setRowCount(testService.getListCount(params));

            if (getRowCount() > 0) {
                return testService.getList(params);
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            errorResult(t);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,for your answer

Comment: Thanks,for your answer .i read http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml  but.I did not understand.can you please tell me what muss I write in LazyDataModel class.how can use testList in ArrayList and how can use and connect ArrayList in/with datatable.Thank you.I hope you help mir

Comment: The purpose of having LazyDataModel class is when you want to have LazyLoading at your datatable. It is actually quite easy to implement. and I have added sample code of LazyDataModel class.

Comment: Basically by adding value="#{testMB.testList}", you have attached the ArrayList to the datatable.

Comment: Thanks Dylan.I underestand now.Thanks

Comment: @Oscar do let me know if you have any problem. Glad to help.